# Azure DataBricks -Permissions denied for root users

Tags: azure, scala, databricks

I created folders within azure storage and configured and mounted on databricks. I am root user and successfully created database. But when creating thr dataframe, getting error that permissions denied..

[image]

[image]

i remounted the folder using regenerated sas keys etc and am Ok with permissions but not been able to get around this particular one.. thanks..

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I tried in my environment and I got same error.

[image]

I got this error when only `Service` is checked in **SAS** which used for mounting.

[image]

To resolve this error, **check the remaining resource types `Container`, `Object`** in SAS and remount it.

I am able to read it without any issue after doing that.

[image]

Comment: would you have %fs commands I can use within databricks notebooks.
I would like to:
* get a file path which I can create within my workspace within GUI environment
* make directory
* copy
* move files
*etc..

Comment: Go through these commands https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#list-available-commands-for-a-utility.